# Why can't my app play the mp4 file it created?

Tags: android, file, mp4

My app takes a short video and saves it as an mp4 file in internal storage but when I then try to play it I get a message on the phone saying 'Can't play this video'.

To test, I have copied the file (via Device Manager in Android Studio) into raw along with another mp4 file (created by the phone's normal camera app) and changed the code to play from raw: with the first I get the same error message whereas the second is played ok. I'm playing it in a videoview.

So it seems to be some problem with the file format. In logcat I see

```
E/MediaPlayerNative: error (1, -1010)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-1010)
```

which I believe means the same thing.
If I copy the file from Device Mgr to my PC it plays ok but if I email the mp4 to myself and open it on the phone it says 'Unable to play video, Unsupported file type.'

I've tried lost of variations with the camera settings including using deafults and other file types but with no success.
Can anyone suggest anything please?

The code is basically from [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/android-camera2-api-take-photos-and-videos/).

Key parts:

```
    private fun setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(videoSize.width, videoSize.height)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(createFile().absolutePath)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(10_000_000)
        mediaRecorder.prepare()
    }
    private fun startRecording() {
        val surfaceTexture : SurfaceTexture? = textureView.surfaceTexture
        surfaceTexture?.setDefaultBufferSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height)
        val previewSurface: Surface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
        val recordingSurface = mediaRecorder.surface
        captureRequestBuilder = cameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface)
        captureRequestBuilder.addTarget(recordingSurface)
        cameraDevice.createCaptureSession(listOf(previewSurface, recordingSurface), captureStateVideoCallback, backgroundHandler)
   }
    private fun createFile(): File {
//        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss_SSS", Locale.US)
//        return File(filesDir, "VID_${sdf.format(Date())}.mp4")
        return File(filesDir, "viddw.mp4")
    }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

My gradle says minsdk 27, targetsdk 31.
Running app on Samsung Galaxy A21S, Android 11.

Comment: I've set up a new project using the cameraview package. It records a video and saves it to a sub directory of the Pictures folder  - and when I try to play it on the phone I still get 'can't play this video'.

Comment: I now see that there is a history of problems with playing mp4 on Samsung

Comment: It turns out that the 'can't play this video' message is generated when the file is not found as well as when the file is an incompatible format. My save and open functions were looking in different places!

Comment: It seems I can't close my own question. I can vote for it to be closed but the limited range of reasons do not apply.